# How Can I Convert Xaml Code To C# (Setter Property in WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, autocomplete, styles

I have A problem regarding Converting Xaml to C# , I m using Auto complete Box Tab order is not working Properly On that Means First we move all the control and at last I goes on Auto complete Box i m solving this through the xaml code

```
<ToolKit:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="TabIndex"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=txtFirstName, Path=TabIndex}"/>
    </Style>
</ToolKit:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
```

Now on Another i m using All Control Dynamic so no Xaml there For Auto complete My All Works Is to be Complete But i m Facing Same Tab order problem How Can I convert Above Xaml Code From C#

```
ctrl = new AutoCompleteBox { FontSize = 14, MaxDropDownHeight = 90 };
//Here We need to Implement That Style
ctrl.TabIndex = c.TabOrder;
ctrl.MaxWidth = 200;
if (c.SpName != null && c.DisplayMember != null)
{
    DataTable dt = sqlHelper.ExecuteSelectProcedure(c.SpName);
    var cmb = ctrl as AutoCompleteBox;
    cmb.ItemsSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>(c.DisplayMember)).ToList();
}
```

Please Help Me out Thanks And Regards

Shashank Tyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (c.Type == typeof(AutoCompleteBox))
{
    //var style = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
    ctrl = new AutoCompleteBox { FontSize = 14, MaxDropDownHeight = 90, Name = c.ControlID };
    ctrl.TabIndex = c.TabOrder;
    ctrl.MaxWidth = 200;

    var style = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
    var binding = new Binding("TabIndex") { ElementName = c.ControlID };
    var setter = new Setter(TextBox.TabIndexProperty, binding);
    style.Setters.Add(setter);
    (ctrl as AutoCompleteBox).TextBoxStyle = style;

    if (c.SpName != null && c.DisplayMember != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = sqlHelper.ExecuteSelectProcedure(c.SpName);
        var cmb = ctrl as AutoCompleteBox;
        cmb.ItemsSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>(c.DisplayMember)).ToList();
    }
}
```

This Code Perfectly works

Answer (score 1):

there is an application which you can do that, which is **[XamlT](http://xamlt.com/)**. 
On **WPF/SL apps**, **you can use XAML or C#/VB.NET** code on some aspects (for example, to create an storyboard or set the image source).

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
var style = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
var binding = new Binding("TabIndex") { ElementName = "txtFirstName" };
var setter = new Setter(TextBox.TabIndexProperty, binding);
style.Setters.Add(setter);
ctrl.TextBoxStyle = style;
```

Comment: I have one more query in above Xaml ... ISTABSTOP property of Autocomplete box is bydefault True  ....if i set it to false and remove the Style then it works then i am able to move tabing perfectly but on autocomplete box the cursor is not appearing